# Retrieving state actors through worker actors in AKKA

Tags: akka, akka.net

I have three actors to handle a CQRS scenario. The **ProductWorkerActor** handles the command part, **ProductQueryWorkerActor** handles the query part and **ProductStateActor** handles the state part.

The way I'm handling the query is by using:

```
ProductQueryWorkerActor.Ask<ProductState>("give-me-product-state-for-product-1000")
```

The code from ProductQueryWorkerActor:

```
if (message == "give-me-product-state-for-product-1000")
{
    var actor = Context.ActorSelection("akka://catalogSystem/user/productState/1000");
    var psDTO = actor.Ask<ProductStateDTO>(message).Result;
    Sender.Tell(ps);
}
```

*Please ignore the path being used to access the product state. It is hardcoded and intentional to make the code read simpler.*

1. Should I be using **Ask** as I have used in this case to retrieve the state of a product? Is Ask called Futures?
2. Should I be exposing the state as DTO to the outside work instead of the actor itself?
3. To change any state of the product, should I handle the message processing in **ProductWorkerActor** or in **ProductStateActor** itself? In the second case, the **ProductWorkerActor** sends a message to **ProductStateWorker**, the **ProductStateWorker** processes the message, change the state and send another message to **ProductWorkerActor** that it passed validation and changed the state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case when you're using Event Sourcing with your actors, I advice you to use `Akka.Persistence`. It handles read/write actors separation and will take a lot of burden from you shoulders.

If not, in my opinion basic problem with your design is that, while you have separate actors for reading/writing to state, state itself is handled in only one actor. Why? One of the points of CQRS is to have a separate models optimized for serving their role (either read or write).

*In example*: you can have one handler actor (eg. `ProductActor`) changing it's state based on incoming commands, and bunch of different readonly actors (eg. `ProductHistoryActor`, `ProductListActor`), each with it's own state optimized for their role. Readonly actors may subscribe to event stream to listen for incoming messages about handler actor's state changes and updating their own states accordingly, while handler actor after handling a command publishes message about state change using actor system's event stream.

**Ad. 1**: In my opinion using `Ask` to communicate between actors is an anti-pattern. In your example, you're using query actor to pass message through to state actor, then blocking current actor until response arrives (which is very bad for performance) just to send message back to sender. Instead of using:

```
var psDTO = actor.Ask<ProductStateDTO>(message).Result;
Sender.Tell(ps);
```

you could simply write:

```
actor.Forward(message);
```

and let `actor` send response directly to sender (you query actor doesn't need to participate with sending the response).

**Ad. 2**: It depends on your case, but remember - you should never pass mutable objects as messages, especially when you use them after sending.

**Ad. 3**: I think that in your example distinction between `ProductWorkerActor` and `ProductStateWorker` is artificial. From what you're showing, they should be a single entity IMO.

Comment: Excellent answers on points 1 & 2. I have got the inspiration to separate the Worker Actor and the State Actor from the book Essential AKKA by Jamie Allen. In that he suggests to separate the state and the behavior.

Comment: The 'actor.Forward' does not work because the actor is a ActorSelection. The ActorSelection does not have a Forward extension. I'm not sure how can I get the underlying actor from the ActorSelection so I can do a Forward.

Comment: Forward is basically an equivalent of `Tell(message, Sender)`. Also be careful when working with actor selections - they should not be used if they are not really necessary. There is some [lecture](https://petabridge.com/blog/when-should-I-use-actor-selection/) on that.